# Setting up SASS with jekyll?

Tags: sass, jekyll, github-pages, bourbon

I've been trying to setup `SASS` (and Bourbon.io) with `jekyll` for a personal blog on github pages.

I've changed the name of the css folder that is installed with jekyll to `stylesheets` and within stylesheets I have two folders, `css` and `sass`.

I start my jekyll server locally with: `jekyll serve --watch`

Then in another terminal window: `sass --watch stylesheets/sass:stylesheets/css`

But I am now getting the following message:

> `/' not found.

Prior to attempting to setup SASS with my jekyll project, my site was displaying. Any links for setting up sass with jekyll would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: not sure if this could help you, but I use a gem called `jekyll-assets`, without the need to also execute sass in background: https://github.com/ixti/jekyll-assets

Comment: Although I did not run into the exact problem as yours, I also find using SASS without plugin very hard (for publishing on github). Therefore, I made a bunch of Makefiles to compile and compress SASS, HAML, and CoffeeScript for [my site](https://github.com/ziyan/ziyan.github.io). I hope this helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

New in Jekyll 2.0 is native processing of Sass and CoffeeScript:

http://jekyllrb.com/docs/assets/#sassscss

Comment: Is this supported in Github Pages?

Comment: @JakubHampl [yes](https://github.com/blog/1867-github-pages-now-runs-jekyll-2-2-0).

Answer (score 0):

hope not being to late, for what you are pretending there are many approaches for example i use bourbon, neat in a jekyll project and use grunt tasks for local development.
Another option is to use a rakefile with some task to handle both programs (jekyll and sass) or as favrizio suggested use jekyll's pluging.

I reccomend you to take a look to grunt.

Answer (score 0):

This happens usually if you have messed with the site `baseurl` in the `_config.xml` and it can no longer resolve itself to find the `index.html`.